# useEffect se ejecuta multiples veces react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, useeffect

Tengo mi hook personalziado para realizar peticiones Get a mi API.

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import configApi from 'api/configApi';
import { AppContext } from '@contexts/appContext';
const useGet = (url:any) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(true);
    const {state} = useContext(AppContext);
    const accessToken = state.user?.access_token;
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchData= async () =>{
            try {
                const response = await configApi.get(url,{headers:
                    {requesToken: accessToken}
                });
                setData(response.data);
                setIsFetching(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
                setIsFetching(false)
            }
        }
        fetchData();  
        return ()=>{};
    },[]);
    return {data,error,isFetching}
}


 
export default useGet;
```

un componente que lo consume -->

```
const AssetContainer = () => {
    const {data,error,isFetching} = useGet(GET_HOME);
    const [enhanced, setEnhanced] = useState<object>();
    const [smart, setSmart] = useState<object>();
    const [facility, setFacilty] = useState<object>();
    const [standalone, setStandalone] = useState<object>();
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(data){
            setEnhanced(data['enhanced_assets']);
            setSmart(data['smart_assets']);
            setFacilty(data['facilty_assets']);
            setStandalone(data['standalone_assets']);
        }
    },[data])
    console.log(data,"Asset Container");
    return ( <> 
             <View> </View>
            </>


            );
.....
```

El  **console.log(data,"Asset Container");** **muestra 3 veces la peticion**.
Entiendo lo del **StricMode de React**, pero esto estoy casi seguro que no tiene que ver con ello, porque el StricMode solo chequea una vez, por ende tendria 2 logs de data y **NO 3 como tengo ahora**.
Alguna idea de porque me puede estar ocurriendo esto?

Info extra mi componente **AssetContainer** esta embebido en otros componentes de esta manera

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation<propsNavigationConnect>();
    const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
    const [view,setView] = useState({
        asset: true,
        layout: false
    });
    const gotToConnect = () =>{
        navigation.navigate('GatewayStack');
    };
    const goToNotifications = ()=>{
        navigation.navigate('Notifications');
    };
    const changeView =  (e:any) =>{
        setView(e)
    }

    return (<>
        <View style={style.container}>
            <WelcomeAndFind name={state.user.name} onPress={gotToConnect}/>
            <NotificationsContainer onPress={goToNotifications} />
            <View style={style.dropdownAndViewAll}>
                <AssetsLayoutContainer  onChangeView={view} changeView={changeView} />
                <ViewAllAssets />
            </View>
            {view.asset ? (
            <>
                <View style={style.assetContainer}>
                    **<AssetContainer />**
                </View>
                </>):(
                <>
                <View style={style.layoutContainer}>
                    <LayoutContainer />
                </View>
            </>)} 
        </View>
    </>
    );
}
```

**Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!**

Comment: Hola Guido, a lo mejor este comentario ya viene un poco tarde.
Pero el console.log que tienes no esta dentro de useEffect.
Es normal que veas el log 3 veces ya que este este ejecuta en cada render de tu componente (AssetContainer).

Este es el proceso que hace tu código:

1. Se hace el render por primera vez.

2. Se hace un segundo render cuando el valor de data de tu hook cambia.

3. Después del segundo render, se ejecuta useEffect y dentro de useEffect actualizas el state de tu componente y eso provoca un tercer render.

Comment: Hola @JonathanHernandez, para nada tarde, siempre es util y mas cuando es tan bien explicado. El famoso error de junior, tenes toda la razon en lo expuesto, viene por ahi el problema, te agradezco. Uno a veces a la hora de estar programando no se da cuenta de estos pequenos detalles. Gracias!!